# How to make a continuous parabolic arc with only 3 known points?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scipy

I am trying to plot a diagram like
[image]

What I am getting is this: 
[image]

Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import spline

equinoxAzi = np.array([90, 180, 270])
equinoxAlt = np.array([0, 38.7, 0])
summerAzi = np.array([45, 180, 315])
summerAlt = np.array([0, 62.1, 0])
winterAzi = np.array([135, 180, 225])
winterAlt = np.array([0, 16, 0])


# create instance of basemap, note we want a south polar projection to 90 = E
myMap = Basemap(projection='spstere',boundinglat=0,lon_0=180,resolution='l',round=True,suppress_ticks=True)
# set the grid up
gridX,gridY = 10.0,15.0
parallelGrid = np.arange(-90.0,90.0,gridX)
meridianGrid = np.arange(-180.0,180.0,gridY)

# draw parallel and meridian grid, not labels are off. We have to manually create these.
myMap.drawparallels(parallelGrid,labels=[False,False,False,False])
myMap.drawmeridians(meridianGrid,labels=[False,False,False,False],labelstyle='+/-',fmt='%i')

# we have to send our values through basemap to convert coordinates, note -winterAlt
equinoxX, equinoxY = myMap(equinoxAzi, -equinoxAlt)
summerX, summerY = myMap(summerAzi, -summerAlt)
winterX, winterY = myMap(winterAzi, -winterAlt)


# plot azimuth labels, with a North label.
ax = plt.gca()
ax.text(0.5,1.025,'N',transform=ax.transAxes,horizontalalignment='center',verticalalignment='bottom',size=25)
for para in np.arange(gridY,360,gridY):
    x= (1.1*0.5*np.sin(np.deg2rad(para)))+0.5
    y= (1.1*0.5*np.cos(np.deg2rad(para)))+0.5
    ax.text(x,y,u'%i\N{DEGREE SIGN}'%para,transform=ax.transAxes,horizontalalignment='center',verticalalignment='center')

equinoxX_new = np.linspace(equinoxX.min(),equinoxY.max(),30)
equinoxY_smooth = spline(equinoxX, equinoxY, equinoxX_new)

summerX_new = np.linspace(summerX.min(), summerX.max(),30)
summerY_smooth = spline(summerX, summerY, summerX_new)

winterX_new = np.linspace(winterX.min(), winterX.max(),30)
winterY_smooth = spline(winterX, winterY, winterX_new)

myMap.plot(equinoxX_new, equinoxY_smooth, 'b')
myMap.plot(summerX_new, summerY_smooth, 'g')
myMap.plot(winterX_new, winterY_smooth/2, 'r')

myMap.plot(equinoxX, equinoxY, 'bo')
myMap.plot(summerX, summerY, 'go')
myMap.plot(winterX, winterY, 'ro')

plt.show()
```

I tried to plot arc through three points (shown in blue, green and red) connecting all same colours. How to make arcs like the ones in the first pic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a spline of degree `k` trough `k` points is not necessarily a good idea. Anything can happen there.

Since `scipy.interpolate.spline` is anyways depreciated, you may use `scipy.interpolate.splev` and `scipy.interpolate.splrep` and restrict the spline to degree `k=2`. (Trying to use `k=3` will cause an error, which is expected for 3 points)

```
from scipy.interpolate import splev, splrep

equinoxX_new = np.linspace(equinoxX.min(),equinoxX.max(),30)
equinoxY_smooth = splev(equinoxX_new, splrep(equinoxX, equinoxY, k=2))

summerX_new = np.linspace(summerX.min(), summerX.max(),30)
summerY_smooth = splev(summerX_new, splrep(summerX, summerY, k=2))

winterX_new = np.linspace(winterX.min(), winterX.max(),30)
winterY_smooth = splev(winterX_new, splrep(winterX, winterY, k=2))
```

[image]

Using those for the dataset from the comments,

```
equinoxAzi = np.array([90, 180, 270]) 
equinoxAlt = np.array([0, 80, 0]) 
summerAzi = np.array([180-121.5, 180, 180+121.5]) 
summerAlt = np.array([0, 60, 0]) 
winterAzi = np.array([180-58.46, 180, 180+58.46]) 
winterAlt = np.array([0, 40, 0])
```

the result is

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain your first statement why one should not use degree k through k points?

Comment: Ok, so this may extend the scope of this question. It is possible to create a spline of deg k trough k points; this would however require additional conditions on the boundaries. Scipy uses B-Splines which do not have this extra condition. So here we might simply accept what Wikipedia states in the B-Spline article: A spline function is a piecewise polynomial function of degree <k in a variable x. The places where the pieces meet are known as knots. The number of internal knots must be equal to, or greater than k-1. Thus the spline function has limited support.

Comment: It's not working with this data: `equinoxAzi = np.array([90, 180, 270])
equinoxAlt = np.array([0, 80, 0])
summerAzi = np.array([180-121.5, 180, 180+121.5])
summerAlt = np.array([0, 60, 0])
winterAzi = np.array([180-58.46, 180, 180+58.46])
winterAlt = np.array([0, 40, 0])
`

Comment: Also for some dataset it's giving the error : `ValueError: Error on input data`.

Comment: "Scipy uses B-Splines which do not have this extra condition" -- recent enough scipy offers `CubicSpline` which accepts several types of the boundary conditions. From 0.19.0, there's also `make_interp_spline` which you can use for parabolas. A good answer anyway, +1.

Comment: @haccks I updated the answer with the image of the new dataset from 2 comments above. It seems to work just fine.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest; OK. Found the mistake. You are right. Thanks for the ultimate answer.